# UK global consultant, living and working in different EU countries

Tags: taxes, united-kingdom, european-union, spain, brexit

I am due to move to Barcelona after living in Paris for 3 years, as property is cheaper there, but still close to international airport, which is ideal for my work.

I now find myself in a situation that potentially I will be working for a French company on a permanent contract.

My first question is regard to who I pay tax to, given the double tax laws?

Also, given Brexit, I can get a residency permit in Spain which allows me to live and work.

Are rights rights conferred as I have the right to work in one EU country??
Or do I need to apply for one in both France and Spain??

Comment: It is better to ask the residency question on the travel area, I suspect. You're asking for two different skillsets here. As a UK with Spanish residency, I think you have no rights in France.

Comment: When I was employed in Italy while being German tax resident, a) that employment contract was subject to Italian wage tax b) the German income tax declaration asked for the Italian income in order to compute the (progressive) tax rate for all income that had not yet been taxed and c) a statement saying that the Italian wage had been taxed according to Italian tax law. The German tax office had a form based on which they decided that my tax residency was in Germany.

Comment: You'd want to read [this](https://money.stackexchange.com/a/113006/88892).

Answer (score 0):

> My first question is regard to who I pay tax to, given the double tax laws?

You live in Spain, you pay and do your taxes in Spain. This is not final word, but is general rule. Elaborate on your case if you have any "but..." doubts.

> Are rights rights conferred as I have the right to work in one EU country?? Or do I need to apply for one in both France and Spain??

I don't quite understand this, can you elaborate? Then I would try to either answer or desist.

Comment: If I have the right to work in one eu country, as a non eu citizen, do I then get the automatic right to work in all eu countries.?

Comment: I'm confident that you, as a citizen from long time partner UK, will have the automatic right to work in Spain if you have the right to work in France. I have had a slight read of several (at least three) recent UK-Spain Brexit treaties, but can't quote anything. I hope government offices from all three countries can solve your question.

Comment: On the last comment:  The comment was correct when it was written, but now Brexit has happened, UK citizens do _not_ have Free Movement rights in the EU.  Somebody (like the OP) with retained rights to live in France no longer has the right to move to Spain unless they become a French citizen.

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't just assume this is how the EU works.

The EU *does* allow its own citizens to work everywhere in the EU, but you're not an EU citizen. EU member states still have the right to grant work visa, but these work visa are not Schengen visa and therefore only give you the right to work in the granting country.

Similarly, income tax is not a direct EU competency either. The EU does expect its member countries to cooperate to avoid double taxation, since that would interfere with the right of EU citizens to work anywhere in the EU. A common test here is to look at the triplet {nationality, residence, place of work}. But in your case that doesn't help, since you've got neither the Spanish nor the French nationality.